# LDAP CRUD with Spring Roo

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo, spring-ldap

Currently making up system with Spring Roo.
Can login with LDAP Server with Spring Security.
But can't understand how to configure LDAP CRUD with Spring Roo.

Roo automatically generates MVC.
From here,
I think have to modify contoller, applicationContext.xml, Entity classes roo automatically generated.
If somebody knows, please tell me kindly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo (from what I know) will not generate domain objects from an LDAP repository. That is you will have to do the "CRUD"ing of your LDAP database yourself.

You can still use Spring to do this with [Spring LDAP](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/).

You might want to also look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389746/ldap-java-library

IMHO I find the LDAP Java libraries and LDAP in general to be so overly confusing. So advance sympathy for you pain.

Comment: Thank you for answer kindly. But it is still hard to make connection of spring MVC(Roo generated) and spring ldap. If someone knows other documentation, please tell me.